# Is there a way to get all sheets inside a folder, including all subfolders? (In Smartsheet)

Tags: python, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0, smartsheet-api-1.1, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I have created a script to automatically update all sheets in a folder, but if there are subfolders, I don't know of a way to dynamically access the other sheets inside those subfolders. Does anyone know if this is possible using the smartsheet api?

tl;dr: I want to be able to access the sheets inside a folder, and the sheets inside all of subfolders that are inside the original folder (and any sheets in those folders etc.).

Thank you for reading, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to list the folder inside of the root folder and to make recursive calls.